# android: using special characters in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in my layout file. My  textview contains simple c++ code. I have included all other special characters except '\0' character. Can anyone tell me how can i include this error in my layout file?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 clrscr();
 char a[100];
 int length=0;
 cout<<"Enter String:";
 gets(a);
 while(a[length]!='\0')
 length++;
 cout<<"Length of String:";
 cout<<length;
 getch();
}
```

Comment: can you post the code and error?

Comment: are display this code in to the textview?

Comment: yes i want this code to display. I am able to use all other characters  but not '\0'.

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing. I have used holo light theme while creating my project but now i want to change it into holo dark.?
How can i achieve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
change parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dark" to parent="android:Theme.Holo"

The holo dark theme is called Holo
```

Comment: can you please explain me what did you just write.?

Comment: you write this code into style folder like this <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

Comment: I think your text view backgroud color is a problem not surely i hope

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
&apos;\0&apos;
```

in the place of `'\0'`

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing. I have used holo light theme while creating my project but now i want to change it into holo dark.? How can i achieve this.?

Comment: @user1977768 : In your manifest file, inside `application` tag there is `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` Inside styles.xml u can change the theme

Comment: no. But how should i change the layout of whole theme to holo dark.?